# How can I edit a replication subscription to include new articles?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have some replication subscriptions and I need to add some tables to one of the subscriptions. Is this possible?

Publisher/Distributor: Sql 2000
Subscriber: Sql 2008

Thank you.

edit: I found this article. [Link](https://repltalk.com/2011/03/14/how-to-add-an-article-to-an-existing-transactional-subscription-initialized-through-backup/)

I'm assuming that this is the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've looked at SQL 2000, but in the newer versions you can just add an article by editing the properties of the publication in the UI then add articles.  You'll have to create and deploy a new snapshot but that's easy enough.  Just start the snapshot agent and it'll build and then push the snapshot to the subscriber.